# __autoload устарел или нет?

Tags: php

Что использовать для автозагрузки классов? Слышал, что `__autoload` устарел и в будущем не будет поддерживаться. Так как быть и что использовать, чтобы в будущем на новых версиях PHP код работал.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 1):

Функция [__autoload()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.autoload.php) - объявлена устаревшей в PHP 7.2.0, а в PHP 8.0.0 - была полностью удалена.

Если в проекте используется Composer, можете использовать автозагрузку своих классов с помощью [него](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)